# How to add scoring function of type Freshness to a field of type Collections(Edm.ComplexType) in Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: indexing, lucene, azure-cognitive-search, semantic-search, scoring-profile

I have configured and indexed the data for Azure Cognitive Search, the indexed data contains a field TimeSlots of type Collections(Edm.ComplexType) which looks like

```
"TimeSlots": [
                {
                    "Slot": "2020-11-23T08:00:00-08:00"
                },
                {
                    "Slot": "2020-11-23T09:00:00-08:00"
                },
                {
                    "Slot": "2023-11-23T10:00:00-08:00"
                }
]
```

I wish to add a scoring function such that the search results are ordered by the latest TimeSlot on the top.
The scoring function type Freshness allows us to get the document with latest DateTimeOffset on top of the search result, but this function does not work on the field type Collections(Edm.ComplexType)

Also, the number of slots for each document is variable, hence we cannot set up separate fields for each slot.

What steps do I need to take in order to sort my search results based on AvailableTimeSlots?

I tried converting the field type of TimeSlots to Collection(Edm.DateTimeOffset) but even this field type was not accepted.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to score the documents based on latest timeslot in a collection of timeslots. Have you tried storing only the latest timeslot in a separate column, and adding a scoring profile to it?

Comment: I want to score the documents based on the whole collection. For example if two documents have the same latest timeslot, then it should be scored by comparing the second latest timeslots, and so on.
The record in each collection is already in sorted order though. Hence we cannot create a column just for latest timeslot.